# Android: error occured while working with custom list adapter

Tags: android, listadapter

In MyListAdapter class I have implemented the ListAdapter, so there are some methods of ListAdapter class to override, am getting a runtime error saying "can't have viewTypeCount < 1", so I changed the return value of getViewTypeCount() to 1 (by default it is zero). Please help me to solve this.

```
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): Process: com.rajesh.musicmanager, PID: 1731
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rajesh.musicmanager/com.rajesh.musicmanager.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't have a viewTypeCount < 1
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't have a viewTypeCount < 1
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.setViewTypeCount(AbsListView.java:6498)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:486)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ListActivity.setListAdapter(ListActivity.java:265)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.rajesh.musicmanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-25 11:03:20.385: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     ... 11 more
```

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.rajesh.musicmanager;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         setListAdapter(new MylistAdapter(this));
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }   
}
```

MyListAdapter.java

```
package com.rajesh.musicmanager;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MylistAdapter implements ListAdapter {


LayoutInflater layout;
String names[]={"efds","vxcvv","cvfvfdvgr","eriehih","jhfgur"};
String phones[]={"1234","43421","34214","341245","3543254"};

public MylistAdapter(Context context){
     super();
     layout=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

 }

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return names.length;
}

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return names[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int j=1;
        return j;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (v==null) {
            v=layout.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);   
            Log.e("error", "getview entered");
        }
        TextView txt1 =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        TextView txt2 =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        txt1.setText(names[position]);
        txt2.setText(phones[position]);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: Can't have a viewTypeCount < 1. Your method: getViewTypeCount returns 1. You should extend BaseAdapter anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your Adapter:

```
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: On your `getViewTypeCount()` change to `return 2;`

Comment: Because that have to do with the number of different rows you have.

Comment: @user3849690 If this solved your problem why isn't it already closed? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    if(getCount() > 0){
        return getCount();
    }else{
        return super.getViewTypeCount();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount()
{
return 1;
}
```

try this in adapter

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.